# Oracle Apex display image in classic report

Tags: sql, image, oracle-apex

I want to display images which are stored under  Shared Components -> Static Application Files. In my table I added a column images with this content:

```
image
______________________
#APP_FILES#image01.jpg
#APP_FILES#image02.jpg
...
```

I select the data in my SQL query for a classic report:

```
select ID,
   
   '<img src="'||image||'"height="50" width="200">' as image
```

from TEST_TABLE

And set the column image with disabled "Escape special characters".

The image does not appear:

[image]

How an I display images in a classic report column which are stored under Shared Components?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to show an image (same image) for every employee in the emp table. I used HTML Expressions.

The select:

```
select ename, '#APP_FILES#mickey550x560.jpg' as image_file from emp
```

- set column "image_file" to "Plain Text" with column formatting > HTML Expression:

```
<img src="#IMAGE_FILE#" "height="55" width="56" alt="image">
```

Result:
[image]